# Nginx: redirect from old url to new one and keep query string

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I need to rewrite old urls to new ones using nginx rewrite. I have one problem with query string. Redirection does not work if old url has query string parameter. My current config:

```
map $request_uri $newuri {
    /old-url/path /new-url/path;
}

server {
    location / {
        if ($newuri) {
            return 301 $newuri;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `map` statement is performing a string match on `$request_uri`. The variable `$request_uri` also includes the query string. If you want to match with and without the query string, you should match only the front of `$request_uri`, which can be accomplished using *regular expression* syntax:

```
map $request_uri $newuri {
    ~*^/old-url/path /new-url/path;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

Comment: One can also use `return 301 $newuri$is_args$args;` for the rewrite.